# What are the recommended ways to change shape of feature maps channel wise other than using Convolutional neural networks?

Tags: channel, feature-maps

Suppose I have a feature map with size $C_1 \times H \times W$. And I need to convert it into a feature map of size $C_2 \times H \times W$.

One way to do this is to use convolutional neural networks as [Conv2d($C_1, C_2$)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html)

I want to know whether there are any other ways in Literature to perform the desired operation?

Comment: any specific goal in mind when thinking about resizing these feature maps? from the way the question is phrased now it seems you're asking for a generic list that potentially include any matrix operation

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero Goal is to down-sample only, but without learning parameters.